# join all lines in a text file in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a large text file. Each sentence is on a separate line and I ant to join them all together in emacs. DOes anyone know how to do this. Somebody has told me I can use M-^ but this only joins one line to the one above one at a time and I have hundreds of lines.   Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace newlines with an empty string.  Move the cursor to the beginning of your file and execute this sequence

```
M-x replace-string C-q C-j RET RET
```

Comment: When I do this it says [No match] ???? Perhaps they are not newlines? I put the editor into whitespace mode and the end of every line has a '$'. Not sure what this means but can I search and replace on the basis of this formatting sign

Comment: I'd suggest replacing newline (C-q C-j) with a single space rather than nothing, so that sentences don't end up stuck to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with query replace, *pasting* the newline.

1. mark/copy a newline
2. start at beginning of buffer
3. Alt-%
4. paste the newline and do enter. (for me the buffer says `Query replace ^J with:` )
5. type space + enter
6. type ! for accept all or y/n for accept/reject per match